# How do I replace a string value with a NULL in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, null, pyspark

I want to do something like this:

```
df.replace('empty-value', None, 'NAME')
```

Basically, I want to replace some value with `NULL`, but it does not accept `None` as an argument. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will replace `empty-value` with `None` in your `name` column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType


df = sc.parallelize([(1, "empty-value"), (2, "something else")]).toDF(["key", "name"])
new_column_udf = udf(lambda name: None if name == "empty-value" else name, StringType())
new_df = df.withColumn("name", new_column_udf(df.name))
new_df.collect()
```

Output:

```
[Row(key=1, name=None), Row(key=2, name=u'something else')]
```

By using the old name as the first parameter in `withColumn`, it actually replaces the old `name` column with the new one generated by the UDF output.

Comment: I didn't think of trying UDFs, that seems to be the way to go

Comment: Your code will run faster if you use native Spark functions rather than UDFs - see the other answers.  (That's why they have more upvotes than the accepted answer)

Answer (score 79):

You can combine `when` clause with `NULL` literal and types casting as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lit, col

df = sc.parallelize([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")]).toDF(["x", "y"])

def replace(column, value):
    return when(column != value, column).otherwise(lit(None))

df.withColumn("y", replace(col("y"), "bar")).show()
## +---+----+
## |  x|   y|
## +---+----+
## |  1| foo|
## |  2|null|
## +---+----+
```

It doesn't introduce `BatchPythonEvaluation` and because of that should be significantly more efficient than using an UDF.

Comment: Excellent, much more efficient for large datasets.

Comment: @cftarnas It is, Python UDFs have relatively high serde overhead.

Comment: @zero323 you don't actually need the `otherwise()` part - `when()` will return `null` by default.

Comment: Could you please show how to do that with nested fields?

Comment: @zero323 in otherwise, I tried returning None instead of lit(None) and the result is same. Can you please explain why you used lit?

Comment: @zero323 when can directly mention .otherwise(lit(null )) right ?

Answer (score 11):

### One-line solution in native spark code

You can simply use a dict for the first argument of `replace`: it accepts `None` as replacement value which will result in `NULL`.

Here is an example:

```
df = df.replace({'empty-value': None}, subset=['NAME'])
```

Just replace `'empty-value'` with whatever value you want to overwrite with `NULL`. Note that your `'empty-value'` [needs to be hashable](https://alysivji.github.io/quick-hit-hashable-dict-keys.html).

An additional advantage is that you can use this on multiple columns at the same time. Just add the column names to the list under `subset`.

Comment: You can also use plain lists: df = df.replace(['null','', 'NULL'], None, ['Col1', 'Col2','Col3'])
I find it easier/simpler to use than a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

The best alternative is the use of a `when` combined with a `NULL`. Example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, lit, col

df= df.withColumn('foo', when(col('foo') != 'empty-value',col('foo)))
```

If you want to replace several values to null you can either use `|` inside the `when` condition or the powerfull [create_map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=create_map#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) function.

Important to note is that the **worst way** to solve it with the use of a **UDF**. This is so because udfs provide great versatility to your code but come with a **huge penalty on performance**.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

df5 = df.replace(str('empty-value'), None)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).