# PySpark - "compressing" multiple-row customers into one row, deleting blanks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I currently have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
+-------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| customer_id | init_base_date | init_end_date | reinit_base_date | reinit_end_date |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| ...         |                |               |                  |                 |
| A           | 2015-07-30     |               |                  |                 |
| A           |                | 2016-07-24    |                  |                 |
| B           | 2015-07-10     |               |                  |                 |
| B           |                | 2015-10-05    |                  |                 |
| B           |                |               | 2016-01-09       |                 |
| B           |                |               |                  | 2016-07-04      |
| C           | 2015-05-13     |               |                  |                 |
| C           |                | 2015-08-09    |                  |                 |
| ...         |                |               |                  |                 |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

and I really need to convert it to the form:

```
+-------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| customer_id | init_base_date | init_end_date | reinit_base_date | reinit_end_date |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| ...         |                |               |                  |                 |
| A           | 2015-07-30     | 2016-07-24    |                  |                 |
| B           | 2015-07-10     | 2015-10-05    | 2016-01-09       | 2016-07-04      |
| C           | 2015-05-13     | 2015-08-09    |                  |                 |
| ...         |                |               |                  |                 |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

I can think of a couple really tedious ways to do the above, but I was wondering if there was a quick and efficient method (maybe using windows? I've only been using PySpark for a month now, so definitely still a novice).

Comment: Please read [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those empty cells you showed are actually `null`s (as opposed to empty strings), you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.first()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) as an aggregate function in a `groupBy`. The key is to set the `ignorenulls` argument of `first()` to `True` (it defaults to `False`).

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'customer_id']
df.groupBy('customer_id').agg(*[f.first(c, True).alias(c) for c in cols]).show()
#+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
#|customer_id|init_base_date|init_end_date|reinit_base_date|reinit_end_date|
#+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
#|          A|    2015-07-30|   2016-07-24|            null|           null|
#|          B|    2015-07-10|   2015-10-05|      2016-01-09|     2016-07-04|
#|          C|    2015-05-13|   2015-08-09|            null|           null|
#+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
```

If instead those blank values are actually empty strings, you could first [replace all empty strings with `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897658/how-do-i-replace-a-string-value-with-a-null-in-pyspark) and follow the method above. Then you can (optionally) replace the `null` values with blanks.

```python
from functools import reduce  # for python3
cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'customer_id']
df = reduce(lambda df, c: df.withColumn(c, f.when(f.col(c) != '', f.col(c))), cols, df)
df = df.groupBy('customer_id').agg(*[f.first(c, True).alias(c) for c in cols])
df.na.fill('').show()  # fill nulls with blanks
#+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
#|customer_id|init_base_date|init_end_date|reinit_base_date|reinit_end_date|
#+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
#|          A|    2015-07-30|   2016-07-24|                |               |
#|          B|    2015-07-10|   2015-10-05|      2016-01-09|     2016-07-04|
#|          C|    2015-05-13|   2015-08-09|                |               |
#+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
```